# Issue with my code backup mysql then upload to server ftp?

Tags: mysql, bash, ftp, backup

I want to try to make my own automatitation backup mysql to my ftp server , but when I try to do it. it doesnt want to send it to my server, but if I do it manually it does it

```
 open xxxx
    user $xxx $xx
    cd $xxx
    put $xxx
    close
    bye
```

bash script

```
 #!/bin/bash
    user=zzzzzzzz
    password=zzzzzzzz
    host=localhost
    db_name=zzzzzzzz
    #backup_path="/var/www/html/storelte/database"
    date=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
    file=$db_name-$date.sql

    ############### Local Backup  ########################
    mysqldump  --routines --user=$user --password=$password --host=$host $db_name > $file
    gzip -9 $file
    ############### FTP details  #########################
    FTP_SERVER=xxxxxx
    FTP_USERNAME="xxxxxx"
    FTP_PASSWORD="xxxxxx"
    FTP_UPLOAD_DIR="/database"
    FTP_FILE = $db_name-$date.sql.gz
    #ftp -inv $FTP_SERVER << EOF
    #user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD
    #cd $FTP_UPLOAD_DIR
    #put $file_name
    #close
    #bye
    #EOF

    ftp -inv << EOF
        open $FTP_SERVER
        user $FTP_USERNAME $FTP_PASSWORD
        cd $FTP_UPLOAD_DIR
        put $FTP_FILE
        close
        bye
    EOF
```

output

```
<p>./database.sh: line 18: FTP_FILE: command not found
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
331 Please specify the password.
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
250 Directory successfully changed.
(local-file) (remote-file) local: close remote: bye
local: close: No such file or directory
221 Goodbye.</p>
```

Please help.

Comment: Remove spaces near "=": `FTP_FILE=$db_name-$date.sql.gz`. Also a good idea is to use quotes because your file name can contain spaces.

Comment: they are sparate even if I change with quotes it didnt wokr.

Comment: Have you removed spaces?

Comment: No , wait wait i understood wrong let me correct it,

Comment: removing spaces near from = solve my problem weird , but it works

Comment: how can I remove the file on the local storage once the file is sent?

Comment: That's not "weird", see bash manual: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html , "the assignment operator (no space before and after)"

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/